# How to figure out how is a request being initiated in a website?

Tags: javascript, css, http, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

So I have this site built on Magento and on the requests section, the homepage URL is being requested twice and I want to find out what is initiating the second request which seems very unnecessary and increasing the site's load speed.

[image: network tab on chrome]

If I click on other, it shows this line is initiating this request 
[image]

Under this line, I see some javascript being loaded from here, so I thought the initiator is one of the javascript files. But I disabled javascript on chrome debugging options and I still got the request.
 
[image]

And it says that the initiator was https://www.yogastudio.co.uk/media/amoptimization/skin/frontend/base/default/js/amasty/amconf/configurableList.js but I don't know much javascript and I don't see anything on that js that can initiate this request.
 [image]

Can you help me find the initiating code that is making this request?
Thanks.
Shahriar

Comment: /*pre-loading images*/
Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){
     var imageObj = new Image();
     for (keyVar in confData ) {
         if( parseInt(keyVar) > 0){
             for ( keyImg in confData[keyVar]['optionProducts'] ) {
                 if (confData[keyVar]['optionProducts'][keyImg]) {
                     var path = confData[keyVar]['optionProducts'][keyImg]['small_image'];
                     if ('undefined' !== typeof(path) && path) {
                         imageObj.src = path;
                     }
                 }
             }
         } 
     }
});

Comment: can this be the problem?

Comment: i tried removing this code, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in Firefox's network tab, it will show you that the source of the request is an image.
[image]

That typically means you are doing something like `<img src="">` in your code, the blank source will be interpreted as the current URL.  I searched the source for that but didn't find any, so I then disabled javascript, reloaded the page and ran the following code in the console:

```
var imList=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(imList, function(img){ 
    console.log(img.getAttribute('src')); 
});
```

This prints out each image's source attribute.  Looking at the list I saw some items that were set to `#` which would cause the same issue as the blank source.  Searching the source for `src="#"` then reveled where your problem is.

```
<img class="lazyimg img-responsive"
src="#"
alt="image"
data-src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/1603184ac748edf036bd176a90da684c/5B983A79/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/31739402_1703759226384844_5600588941112639488_n.jpg"/>
```

You need to remove the src attribute, or set it to a proper image.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I have been scratching my head over this for last few hours.